# Como utilizar filtro para um combobox em c# .net utilizando SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Eu preciso dar uma melhorada em um projeto que estou fazendo em MVC, com SQL e já fiz um combobox que pega os dados do banco, mas preciso criar uma página pra filtrar dados do banco.

Ex: Tenho um campo de texto e um combobox com tipos de dados do banco, não quero apenas um dado, por exemplo se eu quero só filtrar por um tipo, ou por nome. Tem como eu fazer isso sem fazer vários combobox?

Comment: Olá. Não ficou muito clara qual é sua necessidade. Poderia explicar melhor o que precisa fazer?

Comment: @Mariane Ribeiro. Oi, se entendi corretamente, tens uma consulta e a partir dela quer adicionar outras opções de filtro nesta mesma consulta.

Comment: @LuizVichiatto exatamento isso!! Não quero filtrar por um objeto especifico do meu banco de dados, teria como? Desde já agradeço!!

Comment: @JoelRodrigues  na verdade eu estou trabalhando com outras camadas dentro do mvc, Com repository, Dao e a camada negócio, já entendia bem o conceito de MVC ai juntou mais camadas e como estou no começo deu uma complicadinha, hehe...
Mas assim poderia ser assim, pra nao complicar, queria saber como fazer uma pagina para filtrar atividades... Obrigada pela atenção de vocês!!

Comment: Vejamos se entendi. Você quer ter um combobox com várias colunas da sua tabela e poder adicionar vários filtros para gerar uma consulta dinâmica? Por exemplo, o usuário seleciona NOME e adiciona um valor, depois seleciona CATEGORIA e digita outro valor? No final geraria um select do tipo WHERE CAMPO1 = 'x' AND CAMPO2 = 'y' ...?

Comment: @JoelRodrigues exatamente isto! resumiu exatamente do que eu preciso! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá. Pelo que entendi, você pode usar jQuery para adicionar novas "linhas de filtro" no seu formulário (usando a função append, por exemplo) e submeter esses dados como arrays de strings para sua action. Na action você percorre os arrays com os nomes das colunas e os valores (talvez também o tipo, como CONTÉM, NÃO CONTÉM, etc.) e gera sua consulta.

Para gerar novas linhas, existem algumas formas:

- Criar uma nova div; criar os elementos internos e inseri-los na div; inserir a div no form.
- Adicionar a div já com os elementos internos inserindo código HTML direto (`$("#meuform").append("<div><select...")`).
- Criar uma action que retorne uma view só com uma linha de filtro, contendo o select, input, button, etc. Fazer um load e carregar essa view via Ajax, inserindo-a no form.
- Criar uma div de "modelo", contendo os elementos do filtro (select, input, etc), deixá-la com display:none e para inserir uma nova linha no form, copiar o conteúdo dessa div (usando a função html(), por exemplo).

Com essas linhas criadas no form, você submete pra sua action e lá gera a consulta.

Comment: muito obrigada! Ajudou muito!! Vlw mesmo pelo conhecimento ;) Um bom dia!!